# Getting snap apps access to LaTeX

Tags: permissions, snap, latex, paths

Did anyone find a workaround to the issue of snap apps not getting access to external stuff?
For instance, [TeXText](https://textext.github.io/textext/install/linux.html), a famous LaTeX plugin for [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) won't work anymore because:

```
TexText for Inkscape 1.0 will not function if you installed Inkscape 1.0 via SNAP or 
FLATPACK. The reason is that Inkscape 1.0 will run in sandboxed mode in these environments and, 
hence, cannot access you LaTeX distribution to compile your snippets! This is a conceptional 
problem of snap/ flatpack, not of TexText for Inkscape 1.0
```

At the same time, reverting to a previous version of Inkscape seems not to be a solution because the older versions of TeXText used obsolete versions of `gtk`, which do not work properly under fresh versions of Ubuntu (>=18). My version is 20.04.

It also affects LaTeX functionality in [xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp) and more.

Apps installed via snap simply can't access LaTeX.

What to do?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @N0rbert It's 20.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to avoid using Snap/FlatPak for listed applications.

For Inkspace you can get 1.0 from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

and then install the TeXText plugin here.

For Xournal you can also [get it](https://xournalpp.github.io/installation/) from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eandreasbutti/+archive/ubuntu/xournalpp-master?field.series_filter=focal):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andreasbutti/xournalpp-master
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

and then use it as it was planned.

Comment: Thumbs up! It works